# cs50 - population - while 'less than' accepts an equal value

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Positive Interger Greater Than 9: ");

    }
    while (n < 9);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    int x;
    do
    {
        x = get_int("Positive Int. Greater Than Start: ");
    }
    while (x < n);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int y = 0;
    do
    {
        n = n + (n / 3) - (n / 4);
        y++;
    }
    while (n < x);

    // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", y);
}
```

this is what I have, everything else seems to work
but when I try enter in the starting prompt, "9"
the program accepts that input, even though  9 < 9 is a false statement, and therefore should prompt again, right?

what am I missing here?

same thing happens with the next prompt, where the input has to be less than the original input (n)
when I input the same value, program accepts it instead of prompting me to make a new input

I tried changing it to n < 10, but I just feel like that doesn't seem like the right solution,, is it?

especially considering the second part where I have to make it less than the previous int

Comment: "_therefore should prompt again, right?_" Wrong. The condition is false, so that particular loop **terminates** and does not continue (to ask you again.) You've got the ideas of _true_ and _false_ muddled. (Don't change the 2nd conditional. If you start with 9 Llamas and the target is to have 9 Llamas, the # of years required is **0**.)

Comment: Err... `do ...while ... ;` keeps iterating if the statement is *true* and exits the loop as soon as the statement is *false*. What is your problem here?

Comment: @Fe2O3 hey, firstly thanks for the comment,
as I was typing my response below it made sense to me, i might leave it here for others who might have the same problem

so when I test by typing for eg 2, for the first prompt,
since the the condition is true ie. 2 < 9, the loop goes on 'doing'

so when I give the input of 9, this makes the 9 < 9 false,
right i see, and since it's false it does NOT go on with 'doing' the expression
so i should change it to (n < 10)

Comment: @SergeBallesta just a beginner's error i suppose, I wasn't thinking so much about the how it boils down to true vs false,

Comment: "_so i should change it to (n < 10)_" No. You want to continue to loop when an uncooperative user enters values "8 or less"... When you learn about "integer division", you can come back here to work out why `9` is the minimum initial size for the herd in order for the herd size to grow toward the target. TL:DR Your code is fine as shown.

Comment: @detour: Nothing bad with it... But I do not think that this question is really worth existing here. IMHO you should just delete it, or reword it completely if you have a different problem.

Comment: Final comment: Variable names `n` and `x` do not indicate their purpose. Suggest `startPop` and `targetPop` would be easier to understand (and reduce the possibility of writing buggy code.)

Comment: My mistake... Too hasty... Final `do/while` should be written as simpler `while`... Again, if `start = 9` and `target = 9`, then the herd size has reached its target... Do not perform any calculation or increment the year... Sorry... My mistake...

Comment: thank you both for your help
reading your comments have genuinely helped a lot

Comment: @SergeBallesta OP was imagining a problem that didn't exist... Happens... However, there IS a problem with the final do/while... Worthy of an answer? Or, let it go...

Comment: If you want the user to enter an integer greater than 9, you want to keep asking as long as the entered integer is NOT greater than 9, i.e. `while(!(n>9));` or, equivalently `while(n <= 9);` or equivalently `while(n < 10);`. Use the variant which makes most sense to you.

Comment: By the way, Fe2O3 is right that 9 should be ok, so maybe you mean "greater than 8".  8 is not ok because it is a fixpoint for your population growth formula: 8 + 8/3 - 8/4 = 8 + 2 - 2 = 8 so `n` will never increase.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider coding like the comment's requirement:

```
// do {
//   n = get_int("Positive Interger Greater Than 9: ");
// } while (n < 9);

do {
  n = get_int("Positive Integer Greater Than 9: ");
} while (!(n > 9));  // Repeat if n > 9 not satisfied.
```

(Tip: also run spell checker.)

Comment: _**Positive** integer_, so it must be `!(n < 0) && !(n > 9)`.

Comment: @Zakk As the number must be > 9, requiring it to be positive is redundant.  Prompt could be `"Integer Greater Than 9: "`.

Comment: If the OP has to explicitly tell the user what he did wrong, then he must do that check. You are right otherwise.